# IOS 4.3 hide status bar permanently

Tags: ios, statusbar

I'm trying to hide the status bar in iOS 4.3 now that `setStatusBarHidden:animated:` is deprecated:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:NO]; //deprecated
```

The only option that exists in the plist file is: Status bar is initially hidden. Which only hides the status bar at the start of the app.

Cheers

Comment: If the hidden/visible status doesn't change while the app is running, 'status bar is initially hidden' will do. I understand you need more flexibility but I thought some devs would be happy to know they can stick to the plist.

Comment: This worked for me: http://iphonedevelopertips.com/user-interface/gotcha-hiding-the-status-bar.html#comment-55017 gb

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Try this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
```

From Apple Class Reference:

> setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation:
>
> Hides or shows the status bar,
>   optionally animating the transition.
>   - (void)setStatusBarHidden:(BOOL)hidden
>   withAnimation:(UIStatusBarAnimation)animation
>   Parameters
>
> hidden
>   YES to hide the status bar, NO to show the status bar.
>
> animation
>   A constant that indicates whether there should be an animation and, if
>   one is requested, whether it should
>   fade the status bar in or out or
>   whether it should slide the status bar
>   in or out.

Comment: and if i want to make a switch for the status bar ? how can i test the status (hidden or not) ? thanks

Answer (score 8):

But how about `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];`

See the [UIApplication reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 4):

The new method is:

```
- (void)setStatusBarHidden:(BOOL)hidden withAnimation:(UIStatusBarAnimation)animation
```

Works the same except the animation type is an enum now to support various animation types.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
```

Answer (score 0):

`seStatusBarHidden` seems to be deprecated and not working anymore.

Use `prefersStatusBarHidden` on your view controller instead

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```