# IOS: statusbar problem

Tags: ios, xcode, statusbar

In my app I have two file xib FirstViewController.xib, SecondViewCotroller.xib and classic MainWindow.xib; in all I set statusBar at "none"; but when I launch my app I ever see this statusbar, why? where is the problem?

Comment: Maybe this will help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709123/ios-4-3-hide-status-bar-permanently

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid you are setting the Status Bar to "None" under the "Simulated Metrics" section. The settings in this section are there to help you visually design your screens but they have no effect when the application runs.

You can set the status bar as hidden for real in your Info.plist:

```
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true/>
```

In the XCode interface, this is done via Info.plist --> Add Row --> "Status bar is initially hidden" --> YES.

You can also change the visibility of the status bar in code via the [statusBarHidden](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/statusBarHidden) property and the [setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/setStatusBarHidden%3awithAnimation%3a) method of the `UIApplication` class.