# Status Bar Still Showing

Tags: iphone, ios, interface-builder, statusbar

I am getting REALLY frustrated!!

I have tried every living possibility to get rid of the UIStatusBar at the top of my app...

I have tried:

- Setting Status Bar to "None" in IB
- Running `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];` on application launch AND in each scene.
- Going to the .plist and changing the value for Status Bar Hidden at Startup: YES
- Setting that same value on the home page for the target
- Setting `- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
  {
  return YES;
  }` in the app delegate

Literally none of this works... It still shows up on all of my views, and it is SUPER frustrating

Thanks again :)

Side note: I'm in xcode 5, developer beta iOS 7 beta 6, but this also happens on my old ios6 and xcode 4 apps

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade]; from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709123/ios-4-3-hide-status-bar-permanently\

Comment: If you see my post, I already tried that, but thank you for the suggestion :)

Comment: You can also add "View controller-based status bar appearance" and set it to "NO" in your info.plist file as shown in this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17763719/status-bar-wont-disappear

Comment: Had a look at Bram's answer? Looks a lot simpler to me than the 'correct answer'. Works for me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Please try this

```
//viewDidload
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)]) {
    // iOS 7
    [self prefersStatusBarHidden];
    [self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)];
} else {
    // iOS 6
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
}


// Add this Method
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
return YES;
}
```

<s>This code has been taken from [this link](https://gist.github.com/marlonSci5/6006700)</s>

Comment: is that bool method in each class, or the appdelegate

Comment: Implement this method in your rootViewController, Implementing it in rootViewController is global

Comment: I have no root view controller, I have app Delegate, and then a view controller for my one view, but this is an SKSprite project so it didn't populate a root view controller

Comment: I haven't worked with SKSprite kit but should work with your first viewcontroller

Comment: "not so" surprisingly I don't have any Apple Developer Account, and "Surprisingly" I have posted the link to website where it is posted also. you may blame them

Comment: Why are you calling -prefersStatusBarHidden?

Answer (score 15):

What I usually do is add two key-value properties to the `Info.plist` file.

[image]

The properties source code is:

[image]

Comment: One thing everyone fails to emphasize upon is that "View controller-based status bar appearance" is a `BOOLEAN` value.
Mine was set to String, and I almost tore my hair out.

Comment: You really should avoid disabling view-controller based status bar appearance.  This is merely a compatibility option added to make old apps work under iOS 7 when developers have no time or are unable to implement the new way of things.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a method to the **view controller**, and **not** to the app delegate as you write.

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As something occured to me!!

for anyone else ,,
`Make sure you are modifying the info.plist in the right *TARGET* :/`

plus the accepted answer.