# Hiding tab bar in landscape, but it reappears in a specific scenario (bug)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7

I am currently hiding the tab bar with this piece of code:

```
#pragma mark - Rotation status bar methods
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)]) {
        // only iOS 7 methods, code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18525778/status-bar-still-showing
        [self prefersStatusBarHidden];
        [self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)];
    }else {
        // iOS 6 code only here...checking if we are now going into landscape mode
        if((toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) ||(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight))
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
        else
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
    }
    [super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
}

- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){
        [self setTabBarVisible:NO animated:NO];
        return YES;
    }
    else{
        [self setTabBarVisible:YES animated:NO];
        return NO;  //returned when in portrait, or when app is first launching (UIInterfaceOrientationUnknown)
    }
}

#pragma mark - Rotation tab bar methods
- (void)setTabBarVisible:(BOOL)visible animated:(BOOL)animated {

    // bail if the current state matches the desired state
    if ([self tabBarIsVisible] == visible) return;

    // get a frame calculation ready
    CGRect frame = self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame;
    CGFloat height = frame.size.height;
    CGFloat offsetY = (visible)? -height : height;

    // zero duration means no animation
    CGFloat duration = (animated)? 0.3 : 0.0;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame = CGRectOffset(frame, 0, offsetY);
    }];
}

- (BOOL)tabBarIsVisible {
    return self.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.origin.y < CGRectGetMaxY(self.view.frame);
}
```

This works PERFECTLY, with the exception of one case! The code above is in a UiTableViewController (embedded in navigation controller). When I segue to another viewController (lets say in portrait mode), rotate to landscape, and then tap the back button, I end up back at my UiTableViewController...in landscape mode. However the tab bar reappears by itself.

**What would be the cause of this and how may I fix this?**

PS: Manually calling this code to try and re-hide the tab bar has proved to be a futile effort lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following code to viewWillAppear fixed the problem for me (I didn't touch any of the existing code)

```
UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;
}
else{
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = NO;
}
```

Still don't understand why the tab bar was reappearing, but this nonetheless solves the problem.