# IOS 8 and status bar in landscape not always hidden

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, xcode6

I have a Storyboard like this:

NavigationController -> ViewControllerA -(push segue from  button)-> ViewControllerB

I know with ISO 8, the status bar should be hidden in landscape mode (every iphones ?).

My problem or bug is, if ViewControllerA (portrait) push ViewControllerB, there is always the status bar VISIBLE in both portrait and landscape mode. Poping the ViewControllerB to go back to ViewControllerA seems to keep this bug because now ViewControllerA display the status bar in both orientation too. It was not the case before the push.

If i start again the simulator but now ViewControllerA (landscape with no status bar) push ViewControllerB, there is no status bar in landscape mode. I can turn the screen, no problem, and pop to ViewControllerA still no problem. Portrait has the bar and ladscape has no bar.

It looks like the ViewControllerA when in portrait (and push other ViewController) keep in some way the status bar visibility and give it to ViewControllerB .

Is it a bug or have i a checkbox to tick or untick that i have forget ? It's not in a new project created by Xcode 6 if it can help.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you need to explicitly request a status bar update. See here:

[Status Bar Still Showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18525778/status-bar-still-showing)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem in my app. For me it helps to add in custom iOS Target Properties a key "View controller-based status bar appearance" and set its value to NO. 
Give it a try.